# Why do we need to bind to SRC to get an image from the TypeScript file?

Tags: angular, binding, property-binding

I got an array to which I store name and some other String properties.

I also have the "ImagePath". The solution I found was that in the image source we use square brackets [ ] around the source.

I do know that it means property binding, but why do we use it around the src. What is the best way to understand property, besides this use case.

```js
Export class RecipeListComponent implements OnInit {
  recipes: Recipe[] = [
    new Recipe('A Test Recipe', 'This is simply a test', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Recipe_logo.jpeg'),
    new Recipe('A Test Recipe', 'This is simply a test', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Recipe_logo.jpeg')
  ];

 <span class="float-right">
   <img [src] ="recipe.imagePath" 
     alt="{{ recipe.name }}" 
     class="img-fluid" style="max-height: 50px;">
 </span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**At first, for [src] case-** 
As your image path is not static, so you are binding dynamic image path to html by [src]. The src property of the HTMLElement img is bound to the **recipe.imagePath** and if you change the path in the ts, it will change accordingly in html. **The square braces are used to bind data to a property of an element.**

Another important use case to consider is @Input binding. Passing value from one component to another. You can pass some value from parent to child component like this-

```
  <app-child
    [simpleText]="someText"
    [magicText]="'Testing magic text'"
    [pubProp]="pubPropText">
  </app-child>
```

See this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-example and 
can check this blog post too- https://blog.bitsrc.io/one-way-property-binding-mechanism-in-angular-f1b25cf00de7

Comment: Thank you. I'm also checking use cases that include the @Input decorator.